# Mongodb and mLab connection - New to coding -

Tags: mongodb

I have been trying to set up my first database for my python program. I installed MongoDb as well as mLab. When I start mongod and mongo it seems to be connecting correctly to the test database.

However, when I insert my user and pass to start the mongo shell, it shows me this:

Vincents-MacBook-Pro:~ vincentfortin$ mongo ds029735.mlab.com:29735/vinc_personnal -u xxxxx -p xxxx

MongoDB shell version: 3.2.8

connecting to: ds029735.mlab.com:29735/vinc_personnal
rs-ds129735:PRIMARY>

While in my other terminal window with mongod, it shows this :

[initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017

Am I missing something ?
Thanks.

Also, if anyone know of any ressources for mongodb with python, it would help alot as most of them don't show the very basics !

Comment: Mlab.com is MongoDB _hosting_ - Database-as-a-Service. When you run `mongo whatever.mlab.com` you are connecting to the hosted database, not to your local mongod. 
If you want to connect to your local database, run just `mongo`. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I seem to be connected to the hosted database, but it doesnt tell me in the mongod terminal that there was a connection made.
However, when I connect to the default test mongodb, it sais that 1 connection was made.

Comment: How do you expect a connection to be made on your mongod when you are not connecting to that mongod - you are connecting to mlab.com mongod?

Comment: There are two `mongod`s - one is running on your computer in your terminal and the other is running on mlab.com server. If you connect to `localhost` then you connect the first and you see it in console. If you connect to mlab.com then you are connecting to the mlab.com `mongod` and of course not to your local `mongod`.

Comment: Ohhhh ok, makes more sence now ! I didnt know the mongod was only a local db.